# connection refused when trying to connect redis using docker compose file

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have a problem trying to connect to redis using [redis-golang](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) driver.
this is my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: "3"

services:
  driver:
    build: ./API-Golang
    command: go run app.go
    volumes:
     - ./API-Golang:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links :
      - redis
      - db
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports: ["6379:6379"]
  db:
    image: mongo:3.4.2
    container_name: mongodb
    ports : ["27017:27017"]
```

and this the code where I try to connect to redis (API-Golang/database/allSystem.go):

```
redisConn := RedisHost{
    Address:  "localhost:6379",
    Password: "",
    DB:       0,
}

redisConnection, err := redisConn.Connect()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I have tried to change `localhost` to `redis` for the host but still it doesn't work. Here is the error :

```
driver_1  | panic: dial tcp [::1]:6379: getsockopt: connection refused
driver_1  | 
driver_1  | goroutine 1 [running]:
driver_1  | github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/database.SystemConnection(0x48)
driver_1  |     /go/src/github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/database/allSystem.go:32 +0x3d3
driver_1  | main.main()
driver_1  |     /go/src/github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/app.go:24 +0x34
driver_1  | exit status 2
```

Any idea what's wrong?

[Source Code](https://github.com/Gujarats/Go-docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stupid I wrote the `depends_on` not in order I fix the issue writing the order like this :

```
depends_on:
  - redis
  - db
```

Before this I wrote it `db`first. and do not forget to change the host to appropriate name just like in the docker-compose.yml file. In this case is redis = `redis` and mongodb = `db`.

I forget that in app.go I call redis first then mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:

- depends_on will not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

  - Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.
- The depends_on option is ignored when [deploying a stack in swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/) with a version 3 Compose file.